# Selecting all td elements besides one, in the same column, when these lack a uniqe identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I have this [html table](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzyPqv) In which there is a column "date". I have no control over the back-end so I try to manipulate it with JavaScript.

How could I target all cells under the cell with the innerText of "date", given these have no unique identifier (like `.date_item`)?

My final aim is to give them a class through a `forEach()` method, like with the code:

```
e.classList.add("myClass");
```

As I'm new in JS, I don't know how to select all of these td's under "date" column; I never had a similar case in any course/article and What I know of selecting with document.querySelector isn't enough for objects without any basic identifier. I believe I will learn from an answer.

How could these elements be targeted so that I would be able to add a class for them?

<sub>I understand that targeting these via their index in each `tr` is a plausible direction (the only?). I could find the column with the innerText of "date" somehow, measuring its index somehow, and then use that to target all with that index in any given `tr`.</sub>

Update for Rory:

Sadly this didn't work:

```
$('table tbody tr td:nth-child(5)').addClass('foo').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();

document.querySelector(".foo").style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Comment: Please add some code which you have tried and tell us what didn't work about it.

Comment: I didn't try anything because sadly I know absolutely nothing that suits that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original site (doesn't work in codepen due to lack of CSS identifiers there), this code worked just fine:

```
let table = document.querySelector( "table.MOallTable tbody" );

let fifthColumn = table.querySelectorAll( "tr + tr td:nth-child(5)");

fifthColumn.forEach((element) => {
element.style.display = "none";
});

// display: none given just as example.
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `date` column is always the fifth in the table, you can use `:nth-child()` selector to get the elements by index. Then you can use `map()` to place them all in an array. Try this:

```js
var dates = $('table tbody tr td:nth-child(5)').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();

console.log(dates);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="1" class="MOallTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <!--headers-->
  <tfoot valign="bottom">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5"><img src="images/newSiteImage/blank.gif" width="1" height="10" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th align="right" colspan="6">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="35" style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#aaaaaa;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="right" dir="rtl">
                <font style="font-size:10px;font-family:arial;color:#29538D;">מסמך זה כולל מידע אישי רגיש המוגן על פי דיני הגנת הפרטיות. מסירת המידע לאחר עלולה להוות עבירה פלילית.</font>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right" dir="rtl">
                <font style="font-size:10px;font-family:arial;color:#29538D;">מסמך זה אינו כולל את כל פרטי הזיהוי של הלקוח. על המסתמך על תוכנו לברר ולוודא את הזהות בין מציג המסמך ובין האדם אשר המידע במסמך מתייחס אליו.</font>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="MOallHeaderTd">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="MOallHeaderTd" id="borderPrint">שם הרופא/מטפל</td>
      <td class="MOallHeaderTd" id="borderPrint">תחום שירות</td>
      <td class="MOallHeaderTd" id="borderPrint">כתובת</td>
      <td class="MOallHeaderTd" id="borderPrint">date</td>
      <td class="MOallHeaderTd" id="borderPrint">שעות קבלה</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd MOiconTd">
        <img src="images/ok.png" style="cursor:pointer" border="0" onclick="onSubmitFromDoctor('033804001','מרפאת מאוחדת')" title="לחץ כאן לקביעת תור לרופא במרפאה זו">
      </td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd"><a href="engine?templateKey=1500814347918&amp;idorItemId=topMenu&amp;templateName=services.txt&amp;mainView=queue&amp;programName=MRWBZMNSQ&amp;eventType=doctorDetails&amp;idNum=033804001&amp;drName=%D7%90%D7%91%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C+%D7%92%D7%93%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9C&amp;mainExpertise=%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D&amp;languages=%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%AA%2C%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA%2C%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%AA&amp;subDoctor=&amp;clinicName=%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA+%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A9+-+%D7%94%D7%92%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%94&amp;clinicType=%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%90%D7%AA+%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%95%D7%97%D7%93%D7%AA&amp;street=%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%A4%D7%AA&amp;houseNum=36&amp;entrance=&amp;city=%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA+%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A9&amp;clinicLocation=%D7%92%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%AA+%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%AA&amp;gender=%D7%96&amp;phone=9906555-02&amp;fax=02-9906550&amp;receptionTime=19%3A00+14%3A00++++++++++++++++++++%D7%91&amp;remark=%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9A+07%2F08%2F17+%D7%9C%D7%90+%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%91%D7%93+%D7%9B%D7%9C+%D7%94%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D&amp;remark=%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%92+%D7%91%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D+14%2F08%2F17+%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9D+%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A3&amp;remark=%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%92+%D7%91%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D+21%2F08%2F17+%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9D+%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A3&amp;remark=%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9A+28%2F08%2F17+%D7%9C%D7%90+%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%91%D7%93+%D7%9B%D7%9C+%D7%94%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D&amp;generalRemark=%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%9C+%D7%92%D7%9D+%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D&amp;geoZone=%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D+%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%91%D7%99%D7%91%D7%94&amp;setQueue=%D7%9B&amp;drName=&amp;idNum=&amp;drExpertise=עיניים&amp;zone=&amp;city=&amp;day1=1&amp;day2=1&amp;day3=1&amp;day4=1&amp;day5=1&amp;day6=1&amp;day7=1&amp;time=&amp;clinicType=&amp;WSId=IedGuq-NAhNU1XLRksnZfw_&amp;userName=1201526753&amp;id=1201526753&amp;requestType=02&amp;drName=&amp;idNum=null&amp;receptionTime=&amp;dName=&amp;drExp=עיניים&amp;cType=&amp;geoZone=&amp;rTime=&amp;ccity="
          onmouseover="this.style.color='#0082d0'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#004B8B'" style="color: rgb(0, 75, 139);">אבגיל גדיאל</a></td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd">עיניים</td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd">הרקפת 36 בית שמש</td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd" title="א' באב התשע&quot;ז">24/07/17</td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd" dir="ltr" valign="top">
        19:00 14:00 ב<br>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd MOiconTd">
        <img src="images/phone.png" title="לא ניתן לקבוע תור לרופא במרפאה זו.
לקביעת תור, יש לפנות טלפונית למרפאת הרופא
לחץ על שם הרופא לקבלת פרטים על הרופא והמרפאה">
      </td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd"><a href="engine?templateKey=1500814347918&amp;idorItemId=topMenu&amp;templateName=services.txt&amp;mainView=queue&amp;programName=MRWBZMNSQ&amp;eventType=doctorDetails&amp;idNum=033804002&amp;drName=%D7%90%D7%91%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C+%D7%92%D7%93%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9C&amp;mainExpertise=%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D&amp;languages=%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA&amp;subDoctor=&amp;clinicName=%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%90%D7%94+%D7%A9%D7%9C+%D7%93%22%D7%A8+%D7%90%D7%91%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C+%D7%92%D7%93%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9C&amp;clinicType=%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%90%D7%94+%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%99%D7%AA&amp;street=%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%9A+%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9F+%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7&amp;houseNum=2&amp;entrance=&amp;city=%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA+%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A9&amp;clinicLocation=&amp;gender=%D7%96&amp;phone=9991876-02&amp;fax=&amp;receptionTime=13%3A00+09%3A30++++++++++++++++++++%D7%91&amp;geoZone=%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D+%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%91%D7%99%D7%91%D7%94&amp;setQueue=%D7%9C&amp;drName=&amp;idNum=&amp;drExpertise=עיניים&amp;zone=&amp;city=&amp;day1=1&amp;day2=1&amp;day3=1&amp;day4=1&amp;day5=1&amp;day6=1&amp;day7=1&amp;time=&amp;clinicType=&amp;WSId=IedGuq-NAhNU1XLRksnZfw_&amp;userName=1201526753&amp;id=1201526753&amp;requestType=02&amp;drName=&amp;idNum=null&amp;receptionTime=&amp;dName=&amp;drExp=עיניים&amp;cType=&amp;geoZone=&amp;rTime=&amp;ccity="
          onmouseover="this.style.color='#0082d0'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#004B8B'" style="color: rgb(0, 75, 139);">אבגיל גדיאל</a></td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd">עיניים</td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd">דרך רבין יצחק 2 בית שמש</td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd" title=""></td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd" dir="ltr" valign="top">
        13:00 09:30 ב<br>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd MOiconTd">
        <img src="images/ok.png" style="cursor:pointer" border="0" onclick="onSubmitFromDoctor('033804003','מרפאת מאוחדת')" title="לחץ כאן לקביעת תור לרופא במרפאה זו">
      </td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd"><a href="engine?templateKey=1500814347918&amp;idorItemId=topMenu&amp;templateName=services.txt&amp;mainView=queue&amp;programName=MRWBZMNSQ&amp;eventType=doctorDetails&amp;idNum=033804003&amp;drName=%D7%90%D7%91%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C+%D7%92%D7%93%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9C&amp;mainExpertise=%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D&amp;languages=%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%AA%2C%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA%2C%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%AA&amp;subDoctor=&amp;clinicName=%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9F+%D7%A8%D7%91+%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%A2-%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%90%D7%AA+%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%94&amp;clinicType=%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%90%D7%AA+%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%95%D7%97%D7%93%D7%AA&amp;street=%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%A8&amp;houseNum=16&amp;entrance=&amp;city=%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D&amp;clinicLocation=%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9F+%D7%A8%D7%91+%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%A2&amp;gender=%D7%96&amp;phone=5376650-02&amp;fax=02-5376624&amp;receptionTime=18%3A30+14%3A30++++++++++++++++++++%D7%90&amp;receptionTime=12%3A00+09%3A00++++++++++++++++++++%D7%92&amp;receptionTime=19%3A00+15%3A00++++++++++++++++++++%D7%93&amp;remark=%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%92+%D7%91%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D+27%2F07%2F17+%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9D+%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A3%D7%9D&amp;remark=%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%92+%D7%91%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D+31%2F07%2F17+%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9D+%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A3%D7%9D&amp;remark=%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9A+01%2F08%2F17+%D7%9C%D7%90+%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%91%D7%93+%D7%9B%D7%9C+%D7%94%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D&amp;remark=%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%92+%D7%91%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D+03%2F08%2F17+%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9D+%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A3%D7%9D&amp;remark=%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9A+06%2F08%2F17+%D7%9C%D7%90+%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%91%D7%93+%D7%9B%D7%9C+%D7%94%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D&amp;remark=%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9A+08%2F08%2F17+%D7%9C%D7%90+%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%91%D7%93+%D7%9B%D7%9C+%D7%94%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D&amp;geoZone=%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D+%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%91%D7%99%D7%91%D7%94&amp;setQueue=%D7%9B&amp;drName=&amp;idNum=&amp;drExpertise=עיניים&amp;zone=&amp;city=&amp;day1=1&amp;day2=1&amp;day3=1&amp;day4=1&amp;day5=1&amp;day6=1&amp;day7=1&amp;time=&amp;clinicType=&amp;WSId=IedGuq-NAhNU1XLRksnZfw_&amp;userName=1201526753&amp;id=1201526753&amp;requestType=02&amp;drName=&amp;idNum=null&amp;receptionTime=&amp;dName=&amp;drExp=עיניים&amp;cType=&amp;geoZone=&amp;rTime=&amp;ccity="
          onmouseover="this.style.color='#0082d0'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#004B8B'" style="color: rgb(0, 75, 139);">אבגיל גדיאל</a></td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd">עיניים</td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd">שמגר 16 ירושלים</td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd" title="ד' באב התשע&quot;ז">27/07/17</td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd" dir="ltr" valign="top">
        18:30 14:30 א<br> 12:00 09:00 ג<br> 19:00 15:00 ד<br>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd MOiconTd">
        <img src="images/ok.png" style="cursor:pointer" border="0" onclick="onSubmitFromDoctor('030667001','מרפאת מאוחדת')" title="לחץ כאן לקביעת תור לרופא במרפאה זו">
      </td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd"><a href="engine?templateKey=1500814347918&amp;idorItemId=topMenu&amp;templateName=services.txt&amp;mainView=queue&amp;programName=MRWBZMNSQ&amp;eventType=doctorDetails&amp;idNum=030667001&amp;drName=%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95+%D7%A2%D7%A1%D7%9C%D7%94+%D7%A1%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%97&amp;mainExpertise=%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D&amp;languages=&amp;subDoctor=&amp;clinicName=%D7%A9%D7%92%D7%91+%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D&amp;clinicType=%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%90%D7%AA+%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%95%D7%97%D7%93%D7%AA&amp;street=19+%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94+8+%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA&amp;houseNum=&amp;entrance=&amp;city=%D7%A9%D7%92%D7%91-%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D&amp;clinicLocation=&amp;gender=%D7%96&amp;phone=6351111-08&amp;fax=08-6351112&amp;receptionTime=11%3A00+09%3A00++++++++++++%D7%91-%D7%9C%D7%A1%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9F&amp;geoZone=%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9D&amp;setQueue=%D7%9B&amp;drName=&amp;idNum=&amp;drExpertise=עיניים&amp;zone=&amp;city=&amp;day1=1&amp;day2=1&amp;day3=1&amp;day4=1&amp;day5=1&amp;day6=1&amp;day7=1&amp;time=&amp;clinicType=&amp;WSId=IedGuq-NAhNU1XLRksnZfw_&amp;userName=1201526753&amp;id=1201526753&amp;requestType=02&amp;drName=&amp;idNum=null&amp;receptionTime=&amp;dName=&amp;drExp=עיניים&amp;cType=&amp;geoZone=&amp;rTime=&amp;ccity="
          onmouseover="this.style.color='#0082d0'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#004B8B'">אבו עסלה סאלח</a></td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd">עיניים</td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd">19 שכונה 8 בית שגב-שלום</td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd" title="כ&quot;ב באב התשע&quot;ז">14/08/17</td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd" dir="ltr" valign="top">
        11:00 09:00 ב-לסרוגין<br>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd MOiconTd">
        <img src="images/phone.png" title="לא ניתן לקבוע תור לרופא במרפאה זו.
לקביעת תור, יש לפנות טלפונית למרפאת הרופא
לחץ על שם הרופא לקבלת פרטים על הרופא והמרפאה">
      </td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd"><a href="engine?templateKey=1500814347918&amp;idorItemId=topMenu&amp;templateName=services.txt&amp;mainView=queue&amp;programName=MRWBZMNSQ&amp;eventType=doctorDetails&amp;idNum=030667004&amp;drName=%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95+%D7%A2%D7%A1%D7%9C%D7%94+%D7%A1%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%97&amp;mainExpertise=%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D&amp;languages=&amp;subDoctor=&amp;clinicName=%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%90%D7%94+%D7%A9%D7%9C+%D7%93%22%D7%A8+%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95+%D7%A2%D7%A1%D7%9C%D7%94+%D7%A1%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%97&amp;clinicType=%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%90%D7%94+%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%99%D7%AA&amp;street=%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%AA+%D7%90-%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8&amp;houseNum=&amp;entrance=&amp;city=%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D&amp;clinicLocation=&amp;gender=%D7%96&amp;fax=&amp;geoZone=%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D+%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%91%D7%99%D7%91%D7%94&amp;setQueue=%D7%9C&amp;drName=&amp;idNum=&amp;drExpertise=עיניים&amp;zone=&amp;city=&amp;day1=1&amp;day2=1&amp;day3=1&amp;day4=1&amp;day5=1&amp;day6=1&amp;day7=1&amp;time=&amp;clinicType=&amp;WSId=IedGuq-NAhNU1XLRksnZfw_&amp;userName=1201526753&amp;id=1201526753&amp;requestType=02&amp;drName=&amp;idNum=null&amp;receptionTime=&amp;dName=&amp;drExp=עיניים&amp;cType=&amp;geoZone=&amp;rTime=&amp;ccity="
          onmouseover="this.style.color='#0082d0'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#004B8B'">אבו עסלה סאלח</a></td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd">עיניים</td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd">שכונת א-טור ירושלים</td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd" title=""></td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd" dir="ltr" valign="top">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd MOiconTd">
        <img src="images/phone.png" title="לא ניתן לקבוע תור לרופא במרפאה זו.
לקביעת תור, יש לפנות טלפונית למרפאת הרופא
לחץ על שם הרופא לקבלת פרטים על הרופא והמרפאה">
      </td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd"><a href="engine?templateKey=1500814347918&amp;idorItemId=topMenu&amp;templateName=services.txt&amp;mainView=queue&amp;programName=MRWBZMNSQ&amp;eventType=doctorDetails&amp;idNum=011129001&amp;drName=%D7%90%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8+%D7%A8%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D&amp;mainExpertise=%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D&amp;languages=%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA%2C%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%AA%2C%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA&amp;subDoctor=&amp;clinicName=%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%90%D7%94+%D7%A9%D7%9C+%D7%93%22%D7%A8+%D7%90%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8+%D7%A8%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D&amp;clinicType=%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%90%D7%94+%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%99%D7%AA&amp;street=%D7%A1%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%A8&amp;houseNum=4&amp;entrance=&amp;city=%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%97+%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%95%D7%94&amp;clinicLocation=&amp;gender=%D7%96&amp;phone=8411215-053&amp;phone=9319588-03&amp;fax=03-9046848&amp;receptionTime=11%3A30+08%3A00++++++++++++++++++++%D7%90&amp;receptionTime=19%3A00+16%3A00++++++++++++++++++++%D7%92&amp;receptionTime=10%3A30+08%3A00++++++++++++++++++++%D7%93&amp;generalRemark=%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%99+%D7%94%D7%96%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%AA+%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8+%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9+%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D+%D7%93%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9D+%D7%A0%D7%90+%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA+%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA&amp;geoZone=%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%96&amp;setQueue=%D7%9C&amp;drName=&amp;idNum=&amp;drExpertise=עיניים&amp;zone=&amp;city=&amp;day1=1&amp;day2=1&amp;day3=1&amp;day4=1&amp;day5=1&amp;day6=1&amp;day7=1&amp;time=&amp;clinicType=&amp;WSId=IedGuq-NAhNU1XLRksnZfw_&amp;userName=1201526753&amp;id=1201526753&amp;requestType=02&amp;drName=&amp;idNum=null&amp;receptionTime=&amp;dName=&amp;drExp=עיניים&amp;cType=&amp;geoZone=&amp;rTime=&amp;ccity="
          onmouseover="this.style.color='#0082d0'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#004B8B'">אבישר רחמים</a></td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd">עיניים</td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd">סלור 4 פתח תקווה</td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd" title=""></td>
      <td class="MOallVisitTd" dir="ltr" valign="top">
        11:30 08:00 א<br> 19:00 16:00 ג<br> 10:30 08:00 ד<br>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that I had to truncate your HTML as, frankly, it's ridiculously long. There's so much repetition in the `a href` that you could easily DRY - or better yet, use a better URL structure.

Comment: Sorry about the longevity - I copied the code as is. Rory, is `$(return).this.text();` a must? I mean, I don't want to return a text, just map the items in an array?

Comment: I assume you mean `return $(this).text()`, and if so, then yes that's vital. It specifies the value to populate the array with

Comment: Rory, please, one last question. I tried to think how but I think I lack knowledge to understand how to add a class to all cells in the column. I do assume that I should iterate on the "dates" array you added, but not sure how. I would extremely appreciate any clue.

Comment: `$('table tbody tr td:nth-child(5)').addClass('foo')` Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped.

Comment: Sure, I meant to ask --- How do you do so, combined with the code you wrote in the answer? I see it's either `.map()` or `.addClass()`. Adding `addClass("cool");` after `.get()` didn't add a class to all these cells.

Comment: If you want to do both, you can chain the calls: `$('table tbody tr td:nth-child(5)').addClass('foo').map(function() ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
var cells = $('table tbody tr td:nth-child('+$('table tbody tr td:contains(date)').index()+')');
cell.each(function(index){
    console.log($(this).text());
    $(this).addClass('myClass');
    //Do what you want on every cell.
    //if you do not want the first row (the one with date) just skip index==0
});
```

If it is just to add a class, you can simply do this:

```
$('table tbody tr td:nth-child('+$('table tbody tr td:contains(date)').index()+')').addClass('myClass');
```